# How to add stacknavigator header above the tabnavigator in react native?

Tags: react-native, header, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

How to add stacknavigator header above the tabnavigator in react native app?Header must be present above all the tabs when switched?here is the code for homescreen.js that has Tabnavigator components in it? This header could have text also [image: Homescreen.js file] 
[image: Homescreen.js file continue]
[image: Homescreen.js apps screenshot]?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,Text,View, Image, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ChatScreen from './ChatScreen.js';
import TaskScreen from './Task/TaskScreen.js';
import FormScreen from './FormScreen.js';
import Directory from './Directory.js';
import Menu from './Menu.js';

const initialLayout = {
     height: 0,
     width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    };  
var MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Directory: { screen: Directory },
  ChatScreen: { screen: ChatScreen },
  TaskScreen: { screen: TaskScreen },
  FormScreen: { screen: FormScreen },
  Menu: { screen: Menu },
},
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      inactiveTintColor: '#9fffa9',
      activeTintColor: '#ffffff',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#00dc17',
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '400',
        fontFamily: 'WorkSans-SemiBold',
      },
      tabStyle: {

      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        height: 2
      }
    },
  }
);
MainScreenNavigator.navigationOptions = {
  header: false,
};
export default MainScreenNavigator;
```

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary tags react-native and react-navigation is enough to describe your issue!

Comment: Add this in you StackNavigation route options `title: 'Some Title` to add a title

Comment: @Raaj Nadar-thanks-  how can make this header to be hide when I scroll down and show again when I scroll up back? My chat and tasks tabs has another tabnavigator as child.

Comment: You need an eventlistener for scroll https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e

Answer (score 2):

You need to nest your Root TabNavigator inside a StackNavigator so that Header must be present above all the tabs when switched.

Just create a StackNavigator:

```
const RootNavigator = StackNavigator.create({MainScreenNavigator: { screen: MainScreenNavigator}})
```

and you are good to go.